# Ограничение для ответа пользователя в боте вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Практикуюсь с ботом вк, и хотелось бы чтобы на поставленный вопрос у пользователя была возможность ответить только цифрами.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: ВК не предназначено для такого ввода.

Comment: Вы можете написать код, который проверяет, ввёл ли пользователь только цифры. Дать вам его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ВКонтакте не предназначено для числового ввода. Вы можете проверить ввод только так:

```
if not {переменная с текстом сообщения}.isdigit(): {отправить}('Ты ввёл что-то не то!')
```

Comment: Благодарю вас!!

Comment: Был рад помочь)